# How can I auto-indent in TeXstudio?

Tags: texstudio, code

I am a new LaTeX user. How can I auto-indent all my LaTeX code in TeXstudio? Does TeXstudio have an auto function?

Comment: See the Idefix menu.

Comment: I am assuming, that you have TeXstudio in mind. If not, please roll my edition back.

Comment: I am trying to find this function in all menu but I don't find it! 
I have TexStudio 2.10.4 on Windows

Comment: @Sigur in Idefix menu I don't find this function

Comment: @LucaAngelino, don't you have Idefix>Indent?

Comment: Oh yesss! I had the italian language and there is a types in the word translate: ident

Comment: @Sigur Can you make that into an official answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B, done!

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Also it is almost  duplicate with this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327361/texstudio-keyboard-shortcut-to-auto-indent-latex-code that asks for shortcut and have not been answered but have a useful comment.

Comment: Take a look at latexindent

Answer (score 10):

There is also `Indent and unindent automatically` under `Options -> Editor -> Indentation Mode`.

I understand the author is happy with previous suggestions, but I hope it may help others since this question is pretty close to the top result for certain searches.

Comment: I'm still missing a way to make TeXstudio re-format code, for example when I paste code in it does not get auto-formated.

Comment: @Scolytus: It seems unlikely such a feature currently exists in TeXstudio, unfortunately. There is an open feature request with a comment suggesting a workaround for MikTeX users: https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/954/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround if you have a JetBrains IDE, including community editions. You can install a free TeXiFy IDEA plugin. Then start a tex project, which will have a main.tex file, or just create a new LaTeX file in your current coding project. Then copy/paste your TexStudio text, press Command-Alt-L to reformat the file, then copy back.

Unfortunately, the formatting functionality is a bit basic, although you might tinker with the IDE's Code Style settings for LaTeX. Still, it can save time versus manual formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Option >>  Configure TexStudio >> select "Shortcuts" in left pane

> > Expand the option "Idefix" in right side pane  >>

Here you find the Indent, Unindent. You can assign new shortcut from "Current shortcut" or "Additional Shortcut".

Comment: This is no auto-indent, but only indents the selected text using a shortcut. You could also press TAB and SHIFT+TAB. The question was to auto-indent *all* code at once.

Answer (score -1):

Use the menu

> Idefix > Indent

with selected text.

Comment: This is no auto or smart indent, but only indents the whole selected text another level. Doesn't answer the question IMHO.

Comment: This is not the answer to the question, this will just indent the code. This is the exact same as selecting the code and pressing the tab key.

Comment: @AustinDowney The OP seemed happy with it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292023/how-can-i-auto-indent-in-texstudio#comment707125_292023

Comment: @samcarter, I am surprised with negative vote, anyway. I'd like to know definition of *auto*, without clicking anywhere in the editor.

Comment: @Sigur There are some editors (not sure if there editors for latex, but certainly for other programming languages) that will automatically indent the code as you write. But as I understood the OP's reactions to your solution, I think your method is really what the OP was looking for. (unfortunately I cannot upvote more than once :( )