# TeXstudio keyboard shortcut to auto indent latex code

Tags: texstudio

I would like to know of a quick way to auto align LaTeX code where appropriate, similar to the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> keyboard shortcut used in MATLAB after highlighting a bunch of code that isn't aligned correctly.

Comment: Does such a feature exist in TeXstudio? If not, it will be difficult to give it a shortcut. I never heard of this and am using the script `latexindent` with arara.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi : I am not sure. I did some searching but couldn't find a shortcut for TeXstudio. Sometimes copying and pasting code from one document to another causes a lot of additional spacing before lines. So, I guess it would be beneficial to many if they did implement some sort of option to auto-indent code with TeXstudio, if such a feature didn't exist.

Comment: Indents are evil.

Comment: There is a command line utility for this: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexindent